# "position in the sentence" vs. "position of the sentence"

Tags: prepositions

[From an ELL post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/250694/115654)

> In other words, is it common to use "get" to refer to **the position in a sentence**?

Which uses the preposition "in" there. Ngram Viewer shows "of" is also common.

[image]

Do they mean the same thing? Which one should I use here?

Comment: I don't see that "position **in / of**" text anywhere in the linked question. But your question here doesn't make sense to me anyway. The *position **of** the sentence* identifies ***where the sentence itself is located*** (in a book, for example). But the *position **in** the sentence* identifies some particular position ***within*** a sentence (between the third and fourth word, for example). There's no "meaning" to how often either of those two text strings happen to occur in Google's indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Of' and 'in' are semantically very different.

> position **in** the sentence

This refers to the location of something placed *within* a sentence.

> position **of** the sentence

This refers to the position of the entire sentence within a paragraph, for example.

Without commenting on the other question you've linked to, your example calls for the use of **in**.